# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError appears in a specific case

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to deploy a Java Play! 2 application. My Bamboo server is running `play clean dist` which make a zip file that contains the deployed application. Bamboo then unzip the file, and change a symbolic (named current) link to this new folder.

Then, manually (right now) I want to run the `start` script but an `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` exception is thrown:

```
root # pwd
/home/webserver/current/
root # ./start
Play server process ID is 9795
[info] play - datasource [jdbc:mysql://XXX/XXX] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[debug] c.j.b.BoneCPDataSource - JDBC URL = jdbc:mysql://XXX/XXX, Username = lmc, artitions = 3, max (per partition) = 5, min (per partition) = 2, helper threads = 3, idle max ge = 10 min, idle test period = 5 min
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://XXX/XXX
Oops, cannot start the server.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:35)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:60)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:51)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:133)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:162)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:161)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:161)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
```

I've read a lot of posts about this error but nothing can solve my problem right now. I've tried to copy the folder to another place, just like that:

```
root # cp -r /home/webserver/current /root/webserver-current
root # cd /root/webserver-current
root # ./start
```

And here, instead of the exception, my application is working! :-O
My conclusion is that it doesn't works on the `/home` partition, but I can't believe it that!
Do you have any idea or any solution to make it working??

Regards,
Samuel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean and build your entire application. You have changed a class in some way that affects other classes that depend on it without recompiling those classes as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm running "clean dist" to recompiling my entire application. Also, the same package is working on an other partition as I said in the end for my post...

Comment: @SamuelROZE Doesn't change my answer. If you get that exception, that's the cause. Look for faulty 'clean build', faulty deployment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dependency problem. Both `ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA` and `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` was in the lib directory, which aren't compatible! (JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0)
I removed `ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA` from my Maven file and the lib directory and it works. :)